# WiX: How to uninstall a product before installation into the same directory?

Tags: wix

How can I achieve the following: Before product A is installed, uninstall product B, but **only** if it is installed in the same installation directory.

Product A and product B are completely independent and different products, i.e they have different product codes and upgrade codes.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that "same installation directory" means the browsable folder that a user can choose, and therefore you don't know if B is to be uninstalled until the user chooses the folder and the installation is committed to start (because of Back buttons). Obviously if there are file or registry conflicts in other locations there is a bigger problem.

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is:

1. Use a ComponentSearch for a component id in A's installation directory, that will give you the path to that component.
2. Compare that path with your installation folder (after it's chosen) to see if they are the same - I know of nothing built-in to do that. So use a custom action and set a property if they are the same.
3. It doesn't matter that the UpgradeCodes are different - you can have an Upgrade element that refers to A's UpgradeCode and do the upgrade automatically, perhaps the odd part being that you condition RemoveExistingProducts on the path compare property true and the upgrade property set, the one that you define in the UpgradeVersion element. That will clearly affect your ability to upgrade your own product, and you haven't said if that's a requirement or not. If it is an issue, then you'd add your own UpgradeCode in an Upgrade element with another UpgradeVersion property for detecting that, then your condition on REP is the condition for removing B OR your own upgrade property, and both will be uninstalled and your A installed.